# Disable page scrolldown when mouse is over control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, scrollbar, mousewheel

I am creating an ASP.NET Application.

In a webpage I have a Google map control. I use the mouse wheel to zoom in/out in the map.

But when I use the mouse wheel not only the map zoom in/out but the page also scroll down/up.

How to disable scroll down/up of the page with mouse wheel when the mouse is over the map control?

I still want to be able to scrolldown the page when the mouse is outside the control.

Thank you very much for any help.
I hope I was clear.

Comment: I think most modern browsers allow you to click (focus) on the Google map and the scroll action should only be sent to the map's code, and not the window. What browser are you using? on which OS?

Comment: I am using firefox in windows. But I was asking if that can be forced in code so it does the same on every browser/os

Answer (score 0):

On your mousewheel on the googlemap you say you have, you have an event handler about mousewheel. Just add this and you will be on your way.

```
 args.PreventDefault();
```